# HTML Agility Pack - Select node after particular paragraph

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have this kind of situation : various files with the following HTML. I need to retreive only the list after "targetWord" paragraph (of course it changes position in the pages I need to parse). How can I do with HTML Agility Pack?

```
<p>Word1</p>
<ul>
<li>listobject1</li>
<li>listobject2</li>
<li>listobject3</li>
</ul>

<p>targetWord</p>
<ul>
<li>listobject4</li>
<li>listobject5</li>
<li>listobject6</li>
</ul>

<p>Word2</p>
<ul>
<li>listobject7</li>
<li>listobject8</li>
<li>listobject9</li>
</ul>
```

I need to obtain with my code only the list nodes after targetWord:

```
foreach (var node in retreivedNodes)
{
    s[i] = node.InnerText;
    i++;
    console.writeline (s[i]);
}

OUTPUT:

   listobject4
   listobject5
   listobject6
```

Answer (score 2):

**You need to craft an xpath expression to match your requirement**

Assuming that I have loaded a HAP.HtmlDocument with your snippet as var htmlSnippet then

```
htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes('//p[text()="targetWord"]/following-sibling::ul[1]//li')
```

will return the nodeset of li children of the first ul node following your target word p tag.

Comment: It worked in my project yesterday. Now I migrated to another project and I obtain "System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.'"

Can you help me?

Comment: There's help, and there's help. I can't tell you certainly what's going on but my guess is that there is a colon in the item you're looking for that it's thinking is a XML names pace qualifier... So learn about XML namespaces?