# System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.'

Tags: c#, xml, html-agility-pack

Yesterday I posted this question :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182368/html-agility-pack-select-node-after-particular-paragraph
```

I resolved using the solution : `htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes('//p[text()="targetWord"]/following-sibling::ul[1]//li')`

Today on another project with same identical configuratione and HTML agility pack version I obtain the error message in title. What can I do to solve it?

`System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.`'

Code that throws the exception:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlText);


            //var ulCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul");

            var tasksNodesCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[TextValue()=\"Paragraph:\"]/following-sibling::ul[1]//li");
```

Comment: Might find the solution here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511527/namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed-this-query-has-a-prefix-variable-or-u"

Comment: How this applies to html agility pack?

Comment: Can you provide the code where the error is coming

Comment: You need to post the response.  It looks like the response is XML and you cannot create a document with the response xml

Comment: var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlText);


            //var ulCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul");

            var tasksNodesCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[TextValue()=\"Paragraph:\"]/following-sibling::ul[1]//li");

Comment: I added the code segment that throws the exception in the question

Comment: Solved!!! I used text()= instead of textvalue()= I have no idea why yesterday it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a colon in the text you are looking for.

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[TextValue()=\"Paragraph:\"]
```

The parser thinks it's an XML namespace qualifier. Use the escape form " for the colon.

Comment: I have the problem also deleting the colon

Comment: //p/following-sibling::ul[1]//li expression works. Problem is when I add textvalue also without semicolon. maybe that I escape wrong the double quotes in the c# string?

Comment: Solved!!! I used text()= instead of textvalue()= I have no idea why yesterday it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! I used text()= instead of textvalue()= I have no idea why yesterday it worked!!!